# Resample semi-annually with cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with monthly data like:

```
Date          Value
2016-12-01    0
2017-01-01    10
2017-02-01    20
2017-03-01    15
2017-04-01    25
2017-05-01    35
2017-06-01    1
2017-07-01    2
2018-08-01    3
2018-09-01    4
2018-10-01    5
2018-11-01    6
```

I want to take the semi-annual cumulative sum for each month but with a year end of May instead of December.  So there will be two 6-month periods within a year for the cumulative sum. So the output should be:

```
Date          Value
2016-12-01    0
2017-01-01    10
2017-02-01    30
2017-03-01    45
2017-04-01    70
2017-05-01    105

2017-06-01    1
2017-07-01    3
2018-08-01    6
2018-09-01    10
2018-10-01    15
2018-11-01    21
```

I tried this:

```
import_monthly.groupby(by=[pd.Grouper(freq='2Q-MAY'), pd.Grouper(freq='A-MAY')]).cumsum()
```

but it anchors my date for the cumulative sum at Feb-17 and Aug-17 instead of May-17 and Nov-17. It also still ends the year at May so even for those two 6-month periods, it does not have the correct 2 cumulative sums.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I achieve the same result with

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Q')).cumsum().resample('Q').last()
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This question made me realize that pandas quarterly anchored offsets are fickle, and I still don't quite understand how they work. Based on [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383397), the only way I am able to get your expected output is to add a dummy value as the first row whose index is either May 1 or Nov 1. According to @chrisb in that other answer, this has to do with the fact that in the offset `2Q-NOV`, the anchor `NOV` is calculated/applied *before* the multiplier of `2` is applied.

Starting from your DataFrame:

```
# Insert a sentinel value into the first row to influence
# the behaviour of the anchored-offset groupby.
# Inserting at 2015-11-01 would work too
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2015-05-01'), 'Value'] = 0
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Q-NOV')).cumsum()

            Value
Date             
2015-05-01    0.0
2016-12-01    0.0
2017-01-01   10.0
2017-02-01   30.0
2017-03-01   45.0
2017-04-01   70.0
2017-05-01  105.0
2017-06-01    1.0
2017-07-01    3.0
2018-08-01    3.0
2018-09-01    7.0
2018-10-01   12.0
2018-11-01   18.0

# Workaround: groupby with the sentinel value, then immediately drop it
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Q-NOV')).cumsum().drop(pd.to_datetime('2015-05-01'))

            Value
Date             
2016-12-01    0.0
2017-01-01   10.0
2017-02-01   30.0
2017-03-01   45.0
2017-04-01   70.0
2017-05-01  105.0
2017-06-01    1.0
2017-07-01    3.0
2018-08-01    3.0
2018-09-01    7.0
2018-10-01   12.0
2018-11-01   18.0
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I saw that solution but it seems so inelegant.  Can there really be no way to do it without inserting a fake data point and then deleting it?